# Rcpp vs normal C++: header flag available?

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm a beginner at Rcpp (though with a bit of experience in both R and C++) and am trying to write some code that can be used in both Rcpp and native C++.

As such, I am writing some wrapper functions that return data frames, numeric vectors and the like, that get created from various `std` containers.

I would like it so that I can set a flag somewhere, or have a flag that automatically detects whether the code is being used in native C++ or Rcpp.

I was wondering whether such a flag exists, or whether I should just go ahead and create one?

Finally, I was wondering whether this was the best way of doing what I wanted to achieve?

**EDIT:**

This is a very contrived example:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

#define RCPP
std::vector<double> multbyTwo(std::vector<double> input) {
  std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), std::bind(std::multiplies<double>(), std::placeholders::_1, 2));
  return input;
}

#ifdef RCPP
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector timesTwo(NumericVector input) {
  return wrap(multbyTwo(as<std::vector<double> >(input)));
}
#endif // RCPP

/***R
print(timesTwo(10))
***/
```

This the kind of thing that I meant - wrapping a pure C++ function with an Rcpp one. (I know there are implicit conversions in this specific case, but there would not be for the kind of function that I would be building)

Comment: It would be easier if you would provide some sample code. I would (probably) write the main part of the code in pure C++. Using Rcpp-attributes it is than easy to make these functions available from R, keeping in mind that `Rcpp::as` and `Rcpp::wrap` also work for many standard containers.

Comment: "What @Ralf said".  One common approach is a C++ "backbone" with files without Rcpp or R headers -- this you could reuse in another project or library.  Couple it with glue files taking from R and returning from R and you have your project.  Otherwise, keep it simple and comingle for now and worry about re-use later.

Comment: @RalfStubner - thanks - I think this may be a way to do what I want - simply making use of attributes and `Rcpp::as` and `Rcpp:wrap`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel - also thanks. I think I am just going to keep it simple at the moment like you say, and then if required I will package into different files. I will go with the `as` and `wrap` functions first, and then just write some very simple functions for returning data frames I want. If the project gets larger I'll look to split up as you say. Thanks both!